# Why kivy give new children index = 0?

Tags: kivy

I add new widgets to BoxLayout with function:

```
def create_new_tracker(self):
    self.trackers_count += 1
    new_id = self.trackers_count
    self.root.ids['box'].add_widget(TrackerContainer(ID=new_id))
```

When I add 4 widgets with ids: 0, 1, 2, 3, BoxLayout have 4 children with ids in order: 3, 2, 1, 0.
Shouldn't they be appended, so the last added widget should be the last children and not the first?
Isn't that a bug?
How to control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a probably-misguided design choice from many years ago when Kivy was first written - the children list is simply in the opposite order to what you expect. There is no need to control it, as long as you know that fact you can achieve whatever result you want.

I think the reason is that this ordering is more convenient for things like dispatching touches, which goes in reverse order of addition as the last-added widget is on top. I guess that user iteration through the children list was not on the original developer's mind at the time.